# Take advantage of blueprints / waterline findWhere inside custom controller

Tags: rest, sails.js, waterline

I have a *bear* model and I'm using it with **blueprint REST**.

```
// api/models/Bear.js

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

I'd like to perform some calculations to bears based on exactly the same criterias as the standard `findWhere`. Indeed I'd like to be able to request

```
GET /bear/details
```

exactly just like I request

```
GET /bear
```

So I could find bear details with :

- complex query like `?where={}`
- fields like `?name=`
- but also sending json in body like `{name: ''}`
- or maybe even using `?limit=` etc.

The controller looks like this :

```
// api/controllers/BearController.js

module.exports = {
  getDetails: function (req, res) {
    Bear.find().exec(function (err, bears){
      if (err) return res.serverError(err);

      var bearsDetails = _.map(bears, function(bear) {
        return {
          id: bear.id,
          nameLength: bear.name.length,
          reversedName: bear.split('').reverse().join('')
        };
      });

      return res.json(bearsDetails);
    });
  }
};
```

And I have a custom route that looks like this

```
// config/routes.js

module.exports.routes = {
  'get /bear/details': 'BearController.getDetails'
}
```

=> **How to automaticaly filter models exactly like in a [`findWhere`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where) request, in a custom controller, without reinventing the wheel ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I figured it out myself digging into [sails' `find()` source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/1ae1e4caee67a8e5f8e0485e32a7134c8e6ed510/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/find.js). One can use [*actionUtil*](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/cc0c526732e5d86449ef8b99fe55cbc38528129b/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil.js)'s `parseCriteria(req)`. I personaly wrapped it into a service for cleanliness purpose.

Roughly :

**api/services/ActionUtilService.js**

```
module.exports = require('../../node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil');
```

**api/controllers/BearController.js**

```
module.exports = {
  getDetails: function (req, res) {
    let criteria = ActionUtilService.parseCriteria(req);

    Bear.find(criteria).exec(function (err, bears){
      if (err) return res.serverError(err);

      var bearsDetails = _.map(bears, function(bear) {
        return {
          id: bear.id,
          nameLength: bear.name.length,
          reversedName: bear.split('').reverse().join('')
        };
      });

      return res.json(bearsDetails);
    });
  }
};
```

For cleanliness I've wrapped it into